# How to maintain ordering of message in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

We have requirement of message layer and we want order of messages to be preserved till it gets consumed the consumer. We are exploring Kafka for the same. I understand Kafka doesn't guarantee ordering across partitions but within partition it maintains order.

I was thinking if somehow we can make sure that a particular producer (with certain key value attributes) publishes its messages in a particular partition p1 for topic t1 and if we can make sure that consumer fetches messages from same partition p1 .. it would serve our purpose.

In `kafka-console-producer.sh` help , I see below:

```
--producer-property <producer_prop>      A mechanism to pass user-defined
                                           properties in the form key=value to
                                           the producer.
--producer.config <config file>          Producer config properties file. Note
                                           that [producer-property] takes
                                           precedence over this config.
--property <prop>                        A mechanism to pass user-defined
                                           properties in the form key=value to
                                           the message reader. This allows
                                           custom configuration for a user-
                                           defined message reader.
```

Can we control partition where producer will be writing to , using this `--property` option?

Also in high level consumer, can we control which partition it will consume from?
How partition is assigned to a consumer?

Comment: Use common `key` while producing related events to maintain ordering within a partition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820384/apache-kafka-order-of-messages-with-multiple-partitions

Answer (score 3):

Kafka only provides a total order over messages within a partition, not between different partitions in a topic.

If you have a topic with single partition, the ordering is guaranteed. If your consumer if performing well, you don't have to worry.

Assuming you have at least Kafka 0.9, each consumer is assigned a partition when registers at the broker. If you have single topic with 2 partitions and two consumers, each one will be assigned one partition. This information is stored in `ConsumerPartitionOwnershipInfo` see [the design docs for more details](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Detailed+Consumer+Coordinator+Design#KafkaDetailedConsumerCoordinatorDesign-12.1kafka.api). Each partition in the topic is assigned to exactly one member in the consumer group.

Consumer behavior and changes in 0.9 are nicely explained [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/).

Comment: So if I have a strict business requirement where I am creating a list of objects (in strict order) in various servers in asynchronous fashion, I need to use 1 partition or 1 key for hashing this, correct?

Comment: Using only one partition with as many replicas (at most equal to number of brokers) as you want.